# DejaVu Sans Light with XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, sans-serif

In XeLaTeX, it is possible to directly embed Unicode fonts via `\newfontfamily\name_to_use{font name}`.

So I can, for example, write: `\newfontfamily\dej{DejaVu Sans}`, and later write `\dej{unicode symbol from the font}` - this will compile in XeLaTeX.

However I can't find a way to tell XeLaTeX to use the light series of DejaVu Sans. For example, If I type `\newfontfamily\dej{DejaVu Sans Light} (or even just L with or without space)}`, it says `font not found` - despite it being installed on my system.

Moreover, I thought that this may be a font series, so I tried `\newfontfamily\dej[ln (and ln)]{DejaVu Sans}`. Still does not work.

How do I set the light series of DejaVu Sans for particular Unicode symbols in my TeX file to be compiled with XeLaTeX?

Comment: is it `DejaVu Sans Light` or `DejaVu Sans ExtraLight`? I found ExtraLight  font from http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download. `\newfontfamily\dej{DejaVuSans-ExtraLight}` worked for me.

Comment: wow. in my font viewer, this showes us as dejavu sans, light. i will test it with the binding stroke solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax `\dej{text in DejaVu Sans}` is wrong, if you have said

```
\newfontfamily\dej{DejaVu Sans}
```

because `\dej` doesn't become a command with an argument, but a declaration: with `\dej` you're telling XeLaTeX to use DejaVu Sans from that point on.

You should type

```
{\dej text in DejaVu Sans}
```

or, even better,

```
\newfontfamily\dej{DejaVu Sans}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textdej}{\dej}
```

in the preamble and then

```
\textdej{text in DejaVu Sans}
```

---

How to define a font switch for the ExtraLight series? Notice that there is no DejaVu Sans Light. This should be a font face, rather than a font family:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\dejlight{DejaVu Sans ExtraLight}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textdejlight}{\dejlight}

\begin{document}

\textdejlight{A}

\end{document}
```

Comment: wonderful. i will test this while on the train on my way to Köln!