# The unicode character U+2C7A (ⱺ)

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode

I already asked how to embed fonts from Dejavu Sans Extralight in Lates documents. This is the link to my original question :
[DejaVu Sans Light with XeLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125390/dejavu-sans-light-with-xelatex)

None the less, the character U+2C7A (an O with a ring INside) is being displayed a blank square. I picked the letter via Kcharselect, so it exists. It is in the plane Latin -Extended C

Do I have a conflict with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} , that is do I need a different encoding?

minimum working example, as suggested :

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\newfontfamily\urw{URW Gothic L}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\murw}{\urw}
\newfontfamily\dej{DejaVu Sans ExtraLight}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\mdej}{\dej}

\include{./symbols}


\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

math example :$\Dorbit$
normal : \dorbit

\end{document}
```

in symbols.tex

```
\newcommand{\Dorbit}{\mdej{ⱺ}}
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't load `fontenc` with XeLaTeX. I get the glyph, if I add it to the MWE in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: that did not help, should i also remove inputenc?

Comment: Please, add a MWE.

Answer (score 3):

You should use neither `fontenc` nor `inputenc` with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads amsmath
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{centernot}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\dej{DejaVu Sans ExtraLight}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\mdej}{\dej}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes} % use it instead of newtxtext

\newcommand{\Dorbit}{\mdej{ⱺ}}

\begin{document}

math example: $\Dorbit$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\input` should be used for loading a macro file, rather than `\include`. Don't load `xunicode` nor `xltxtra` (the last one can be loaded if you *really* need its extra features, which is quite improbable).

Comment: i found out, that this gylph does not exist in dejavu sans extralight actually. so i am confused why my fontviewer was showing it, and how you actually got it. See here: http://www.fonts2u.com/dejavu-sans-extralight.font

it does not have the latin extended C plane

Comment: @Sean You should get the fonts straight from the source, https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/ because not all sites redistributing them have the latest version.  This is generally true with fonts, not just with DejaVu.

Comment: @Sean It seems that Kcharselect shows characters even if they are not in the selected font. I was bitten by this recently. The relevant bug is: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97420.